# Bash: Grep regular expression failing to work

Tags: bash, regex, grep

When using `grep` like so:

```
ps aux | grep 'processname' | awk '{print $2}'
```

The `PIDs` of processes with`processname` is returned. When using this:

```
ps aux | grep '^processname' | awk '{print $2}'
```

I'm trying to get processes which commandline start with `processname`, but it doesn't work.

Example processes running:

```
processname
other_processname
```

I would like to get the `PID` of the first option, because `processname` is the start of the command.

I've also tried used the `-E, -e, -w` flags, and they all return the same result. What's incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` marks the start of a line, not a field.

```
ps aux | grep ' processname'
```

will come closer, but it still might give some false positives.

Since the width of the other columns is fixed, you could also use

```
grep '^.\{65\}processname'
```

Here, `^.\{65\}` is exactly 65 character from the start of the line. The exact number may vary on your system.

Since you're already using awk, this would probably be a better option:

```
ps aux | awk '{ if ($11 == "processname") print $2 }'
```

You can also reformat the output of ps to make grepping easier:

```
ps ax -o pid,args | grep '^[^ ]\+ processname'
```

The switch `-o pid,args` makes ps display only the PID and the command with arguments. The expression `^[^ ]\+` matches all characters from the start of the line up to the first space.

Comment: *Field* in awk's sense, e.g., `$2` denotes the second field.

Comment: `cmd` displays the bare commmand, e.g., only `processname`, without the arguments.

Comment: You're right. I mixed up `cmd` and `comm`. The latter displays the bare command. `cmd` and `args` are aliases.